# to find class distribution for breast cancer data set - python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As a part of the assignment of the applied machine learning course in python ( assignment1 question 2 ) I have to find the class distribution of the breast cancer data set ( sklearn.dataset) . The code I used is give below. the function `answer_one` converts the data set into a data frame of 569x30 ( 569 instances and 30 features). The code gives me an error which states `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'target'`. Can anyone help?

The code is

```
def answer_two():
    cancerdf = answer_one()
    counts = cancerdf.target.value_counts(ascending=True)
    counts.index = "malignant benign".split()
    return counts
answer_two()
```

Comment: Can you paste the answer_one() definition here. I guess there is no ' target ' variable in your dataset.

Comment: @Indi, the error says `tuple`. but should have been a dataframe given the commands that follow in the next lines. `target` could be a variable in the dataset but `cancerdf` is a tuple.

Comment: Right. I was concentrating on this line - the function answer_one converts the data set into a data frame of 569x30 ( 569 instances and 30 features) - thought Solly already has the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

The error mentions `'tuple' object has no...`. But it should have been a dataframe. Which means that your `answer_one()` function doesn't return a dataframe but a tuple. Check the `type` of `cancerdf`. If it says `cancerdf` is a tuple then you need to check that part out.

Comment: Thanks a lot . it did work . in answer_one I changed the return statement to data frame . earlier it was return data.shape

Comment: good to hear that. You can accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

```
def answer_two():

    cancerdf = answer_one()
    counts = cancerdf.target.value_counts(ascending = True)
    target = pd.Series(counts)
    target.index=['malignant', 'benign']

    return target


answer_two()
```

"This will return a series of index = ['malignant', 'benign']"

Answer (score -1):

A correction to the previous code:

```
def answer_two():
    target = answer_one().value_counts('target')
    target.index = ['benign', 'malignant']
    
    return target
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34774554)

Comment: The question was - I quote: 'Can anyone help?'  I am trying to help, even though my answer might be incorrect, nevertheless I am trying. What other answer do you expect to an open question?

Comment: The main issue that I see here is that this could be a comment on the previous answer. Providing an explanation to yout solution would be great. PS; I didn't downvoted this. :^)